# Changes "127.02" to "27.02"

Tags: vba, excel

Here's how my sheet works:

I paste information from Amazon into one sheet.  This includes the amount, which in this case, is $127.02.

I use a macro to move this information to the next sheet so it's organized in a database type thing.  However, when I run the macro, it is taking 127.02 and changing it to 27.02...  Spooky.

I am certain that it is pasting as 127.02 and not 27.02.  The change only occurs when the macro is run and it is moved.

Both the cell it is originally pasted into and the cell it is moved to are in general format.

Here's the VBA:

```
 Sub ToCurrent()
    'Rename sheets
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet: Set wsPaste = Sheets("AMPaste")
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet: Set wsCurrent = Sheets("AMCurrent")

    'Paste AMPaste to AMCurrent
    NextRow = wsCurrent.Cells(wsCurrent.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsPaste.Range("A3:F3").Copy
    wsCurrent.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Clear AMPaste Worksheet
    Sheets("AMPaste").Range("A4:E200").Clear

    'Remove pics from AMPaste Worksheet
    Dim Pic As Object
    For Each Pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
    Pic.Delete
    Next Pic

    'Add text to A4
    Range("$A$4").Value = "'Paste Case Here"
    Range("$A$4").Font.Bold = True

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.  I'm not sure why it would be dropping the 1 and as far as I know this is the only number it's done it to.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your worksheets?

Comment: Do you have any `Worksheet_Change` macros running in the background by chance?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a sample sheet because the person who I made this book for (even though I told them NOT to) removed the content that was to be pasted.  Super frustrating since now -I- can't experience the issue by my own hand, though I did watch them reproduce the error.  As far as worksheet_change goes, I do not.

Comment: Have you tried using `wsPaste.Range("A3:F3").Copy wsCurrent.Range("A" & NextRow)`

Comment: Are you just referring to both of those strings being on one line unlike mine being on two?  If so, no, I haven't tried it, but I can.

Comment: Yes, but without any `PasteSpecial`. Can you try just what I've provided?

Comment: @Heather does it shows 27.02 as well on the formula bar?  Is some small white boxes pasted from the site blocking your view?